# How to sort the letters in a string into alphabetical order in c / c++?

Tags: c++, c, sorting

hi all
in this code when i write AaBc it writes ' ABab' .
what should i change in this code ,if i want it writes like ' AaBb '???

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (void)
{
    char string[128], temp;
    int n, i, j;

    printf("\nEnter string: ");
    gets(string);

    n = strlen(string);

    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (string[i] > string[j])
            {
                temp = string[i];
                string[i] = string[j];
                string[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n%s", string);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It never writes `AaBb` when you're entering `AaBc`

Comment: I edited the title since it didn't match the example code.

Comment: This looks like C and not C++. Or is it just me?

Comment: @kevin, looks like the language C/C++ to me ;)

Comment: You should put the proper attribution in your answer on [yahoo answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AqBg.4eFk43HruplwshIIQTsy6IX;_ylv=3?qid=20110521102906AAkBejS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ASCII value of `'A'` and `'a'` are not the same. `'A' == 65` and `'a' == 97`.

So, when you compare, you need to compare using either `tolower` or `toupper` to make sure that your value is right. After you make that comparison, you need to *then* also compare to see if it's upper versus lowercase (to ensure upper, then lower ordering).

Answer (score 4):

You first need to do a case insensitive comparison and, if the letters are the same, a case sensitive comparison.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (void)
{
    char string[128], temp;
    int n, i, j;

    printf("\nEnter string: ");
    gets(string);
    n = strlen(string);

    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            int  s = tolower(string[i]) - tolower(string[j]);
            if ( s == 0 )
            {   // letters are the same... now watch out for case
                s = string[i] - string[j];
            }

            if (s > 0)
            {
                temp = string[i];
                string[i] = string[j];
                string[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n%s", string);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a customer comparison function to pass to sort (or qsort).

```
bool comp(char c1, char c2)
{
    return tolower(c1) < tolower(c2);
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "ABab";
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end(), comp);
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's probably not exactly what is required. your code with input "ABabABab" would give "AaAaBbBb" which isn't really "sorted".

Comment: True, but I assume the OP could figure out to put whatever logic in the comparison function that was needed.