# How can I compare if a char is higher or lower in alphabetical order than another?

Tags: c++, char, singly-linked-list, alphabetical

Pretty much as the title. I'm writing a linked list and I need a function to sort the list alphabetically, and I'm pretty stumped. Not sure how this has never come up before, but I have no idea how to do it other than to create my own function listing the entire alphabet and comparing positions of letters from scratch.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Edit for clarity:

I've got a linear linked list of class objects, each class object has a char name, and I'm writing a function to compare the name of each object in the list, to find the highest object alphabetically, and then find the next object down alphabetically, etc, linking them together as I go. I already have a function that does this for an int field, so I just need to rewrite it to compare inequalities between alphabetical characters where a is largest and z is smallest.

In hindsight that was probably a lot more relevant than I thought.

I think a couple of the answers I've gotten already should work so I'll pop back and select a best answer once I've gotten it working.

I'm also working with g++ and unity.

Comment: Why not just `a > b`? Characters appear in alphabetical order in their enumeration.

Comment: What Quirliom said. But you don't even have to worry about that, use `strcmp()` and `stricmp()` to compare strings. It is faster than doing it yourself.

Comment: @Quirliom: Not true. In alphabetical order, 'a' comes be for 'B'.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That will depend on the encoding, but yeah. When comparing different case it becomes a whole new problem. Thats what `stricmp()` is there for.

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25462037/315052) what you had in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that in general case the best approach will be to use std::char_traits:

```
char a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
std::locale loc;
a = std::tolower(a, loc);
b = std::tolower(b, loc);

std::cout << std::char_traits::compare(&a, &b, 1u);
```

But in many common situations you can simply compare chars as you do it with other integer types.

Comment: upvoted! nice answer, completely forgot about the traits compare. You can also compare C-like strings with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctype.h>

 void main(void) {
  char a = 'X', b = 'M';
  printf("%i\n", a < b);
  printf("%i\n", b < a);

  printf("%i\n", 'a' < 'B'); 
  printf("%i\n", tolower('a') < tolower('B'));
 }
```

prints out:

```
 0
 1
 0
 1
```

`char`s are still numbers, and can be compared as such. The upper case letters and lower case letters are all in order, with the upper case letters before the lower. (Such that 'Z' < 'a'.) See an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Can you modify your code to handle upper and lower case?  Not blowing steam at you, just curious.

Comment: Handle how? Like, make it case insensitive?

Comment: @JayKominek Same point, Benjamin Lindlley brought up with my answer and various other comments.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say, but I'll note that I didn't claim ASCII puts the numeric values in alphabetical order. In fact, I note that the upper case letters precede the lower.

Comment: @JayKominek Yes, maybe putting code to handle case sensitivity.  Not a must, just a nice-to-have ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your list contains `char*` as data (it better contain [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)s as data). If the list is composed of the latter, you can simply sort using the overloaded `std::string`'s `operator<`, like

```
return str1 < str2; // true if `str1` is lexicographically before `str2`
```

If your list is made of C-like null-terminated strings, then you can sort them using [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) like

```
return std::strcmp(s1, s2);
```

or use the [`std::char_traits::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/compare) (as mentioned by @Anton) like

```
return std::char_traits<char>::compare(s1, s2, std::min(std::strlen(s1), std::strlen(s2)));
```

or sort them via temporary `std::string`s (most expensive), like

```
return std::string(s1) < std::string(s2); // here s1 and s2 are C-strings
```

If your list simply contains characters, then, as mentioned in the comments,

```
return c1 < c2; // returns true whenever c1 is before c2 in the alphabet
```

If you don't care about uppercase/lowercase, then you can use [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) to transform the character into uppercase, then always compare the uppercase.

Comment: Constructing two temporary strings to do a comparison... premature pessimisation?  Not bad advice for a beginner, but only need the left-hand-side argument to be a string for that (second overload marked (9) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)), and worth mentioning `strcmp` is a *much* faster albeit more cryptic option.  Hopefully beginners will avoid C-style/ASCIIZ strings as much as possible anyway....

Comment: @TonyD thanks, indeed, you're right, I added the `strcmp` function. I would definitely avoid the temp method.

Comment: Isn't `return std::char_traits<char>::compare(s1, s2, std::min(strlen(s1), strlen(s2)));` buggy - firstly [`compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/compare) returns a negative, 0 or positive number for less, equal and greater, so you'd want to test for `< 0`, and also the `min` of `strlen`s means you consider a string to be equal to any leading component of it (you'd need to handle the compare == 0 case by returning `strlen(lhs) < strlen(rhs)`.

Comment: @TonyD not sure I'd say its "buggy", but indeed you have to test. And indeed, the strings will compare as equal up to leading components (which I now realized is not the case for `strcmp`).

Comment: Re buggy - all I meant is that having started with `return str1 < str2;`, I'd just assumed you wanted to list functional equivalents (whether for `const char*` or not).... e.g. `std::strcmp(s1, s2) < 0`... clearly my mistaken assumption - sorry.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this ASCII table, all of the alphanumeric characters appear in the correct alphabetical order, regarding their actual values:

[image]

*"Is there any easy way to do this?"*

So yes, comparing the character values will provide to have them sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm repeating myself here, but no, this is not true. In alphabetical order, 'B' does not precede 'a'.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, I've seen your comment, good point. One has to _normalize_ what's meant by _alphabetical order_.

Answer (score 0):

would something like below suffice ? convert everything to upper first.

```
class compareLessThanChar{
public:
    bool operator()(const char a, const char b)
    { return toupper(a) < toupper(b); }
}


std::multiset<char, compareLessThanChar> sortedContainer;
```