# How do I sort a linked list in a alphabetical order in c

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to sort my linked list in alphabetical order, but it looks like my sorting algorithm doesn't. How can I sort my list?

```
typedef struct  s_file
{
    char        *file_name;
    struct      s_file *next;
}               t_file;

void    sort_alpha(t_file **begin_list)
{
    t_file  *list;
    char    *tmp;

    list = *begin_list;
    if (list)
    {
        while (list)
        {
            if (strcmp(list->file_name, list->next->file_name) < 0)
            {
                tmp = list->file_name;
                list->file_name = list->next->file_name;
                list->next->file_name = tmp;
            }
            list = list->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to compare each element with every other element to find it's  position in the sorted list. (Yes, there are better algorithms which don't require O(n^2 )comparisons). Read about bubble sort or selection sort.

Comment: It's almost easier to create an array of pointers from your list and then call `qsort` on the array and then repopulate your list in sort-order (a heck of a lot faster too for anything but trivially small lists)

Comment: All the code does is move the largest name to the last node in the list. The code needs an outer loop to repeat the process, until no nodes are detected to be out of order. Technically, this isn't sorting the list, it's sorting the names in the nodes in the list, as opposed to sorting the nodes (structures). One alternative is to start with an empty list, then to remove nodes from the original list and "insert" them into the initially empty list in order, resulting in a sorted list when the original list is emptied.

Comment: @SilentMonk The presented "alpha sort" algorithm is **always** faster then `bubble sort` and **always much faster** then `selection sort.` Its best time complexity is better than O(n) and for the worst case is always less then O(n^2). The selection sort complexity is always O(n^2).  See: [Time complexity chart](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)  @DavidC.Ranking Of course `qsort` is on average much faster than `bubble sort`.  @rcgldr With presented complete algorithm there is no need for outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the code once more I have optimized it to match the original intention of the @TenTen Peter. The outer loop is not needed. Sorting is done correctly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

// definition of the structure (global scope)
typedef struct  s_file
{
    char        *file_name;
    struct      s_file *next;
} t_file;

int static counter = 0;

void sort_alpha(t_file **begin_list)
{
  t_file    *list;
  char  *tmp;
  list = *begin_list;
  if (list)
    {
        while (list && list->next)
        {
            if (strcmp(list->file_name, list->next->file_name) > 0)
            {
                tmp = list->file_name;
                list->file_name = list->next->file_name;
                list->next->file_name = tmp;
                counter = counter + 1;
                printf("swap=%d\n",counter);
            }
        list = list->next;
        }
    }
}

int list_size(t_file **alst)
{
    int size = 0;
    t_file  *conductor;  // This will point to each node as it traverses the list
    conductor = *alst;      
    if ( conductor != 0 ) 
    {
        size = 1;
        while ( conductor->next != 0)
        {
            conductor = conductor->next;
            size = size + 1;
        }
     }
    return size;
}

void list_add(t_file **alst, t_file *newElement)
{
    printf("list_add->");
    if (newElement)
    {
         newElement->next = *alst;
         *alst = newElement;

        // Printing the added element
        printf("list_add:newElement=%s\n",(*alst)->file_name);

        // sorting:
        sort_alpha(alst); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NULL entry\n");
    }
}

t_file  *newEntry(char *file_name)
{
    t_file *file;
    file = (t_file *) malloc( sizeof(t_file) );
    printf("newEntry:file_name= %s\n",file_name);
    if (file)
    {
       file->file_name = file_name;
       file->next = NULL;
   }
   return (file);
}

// Untested
void read_dir(char *dir_name, t_file **begin_list)
{
    DIR *dir;   
    struct dirent *entry;
    dir = opendir(dir_name);
    if (!dir)
   {
        perror(dir_name);
        return;
   }
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        list_add(begin_list, newEntry(entry->d_name));
   }    
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    t_file *s,*iter,*e2,*e3,*e4,*e5,*e6,*e7;
    int j=0;
    
    printf("*Program Start*\n");        

    // Creating entries:
    s  = newEntry("dHea");
    e2 = newEntry("bbcx");
    e3 = newEntry("abcd");
    e4 = newEntry("cbcd");
    e5 = newEntry("cbad");
    e6 = newEntry("bbcd");
    e7 = newEntry("cbaa");

    // Adding entries to the list and sorting at the same time
    list_add(&s, e2);
    list_add(&s, e3);
    list_add(&s, e4);
    list_add(&s, e5);
    list_add(&s, e6);
    list_add(&s, e7);
    
    // It was done by:
    // read_dir(av[1], &s); // Untested
    
    // Print the sorted list
    iter = s;
    while (iter)
    {
        j++;
        printf("Printing sorted list: element %d = %s\n",j,iter->file_name);
        iter = iter->next;
    }

    printf("*Program End**\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*Program Start*
newEntry:file_name= dHea
newEntry:file_name= bbcx
newEntry:file_name= abcd
newEntry:file_name= cbcd
newEntry:file_name= cbad
newEntry:file_name= bbcd
newEntry:file_name= cbaa
list_add->list_add:newElement=bbcx
list_add->list_add:newElement=abcd
list_add->list_add:newElement=cbcd
swap=1
swap=2
list_add->list_add:newElement=cbad
swap=3
swap=4
list_add->list_add:newElement=bbcd
swap=5
list_add->list_add:newElement=cbaa
swap=6
swap=7
swap=8
Printing sorted list: element 1 = abcd
Printing sorted list: element 2 = bbcd
Printing sorted list: element 3 = bbcx
Printing sorted list: element 4 = cbaa
Printing sorted list: element 5 = cbad
Printing sorted list: element 6 = cbcd
Printing sorted list: element 7 = dHea
*Program End**
```

Code is here: [code](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/nuKYhx)

Edit: Since one may have concerns regarding efficiency of the above algorithm I have added a swap counter. It counts how many times the need to swap pointers had occurred. (Please note that no copying of is involved).
For the above data the algorithm seems to be very efficient. Only 8 swaps for our list of 7 elements!

To compare these are sorting times for various sorting algorithms:

> Bubble Sort [Best: O(n), Worst:O(N^2)]
>
> Selection Sort [Best/Worst: O(N^2)]
>
> Insertion Sort [Best: O(N), Worst:O(N^2)]
>
> Quicksort [Best: O(N lg N), Avg: O(N lg N), Worst:O(N^2)]
>
> Heapsort [Best/Avg/Worst: O(N lg N)]
>
> Counting sort [Best/Avg/Worst: O(N)]
>
> Radix sort [Best/Avg/Worst: O(N)]

Source wiki [Sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Lets us compare the above algorithm with the **classical bubble sort algorithm** for the same set of data.
This is the testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int count = 0; 

int main(void) {

    char name[10][8], tname[10][8], temp[8];
    int i, j, n;

    printf("Enter the number of names\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter %d names\n", n);

    // reading names
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", name[i]);
        strcpy(tname[i], name[i]);
    }

    // standard bubble sort  
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(name[i], name[j]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, name[i]);
                strcpy(name[i], name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j], temp);

                count = count + 1;
                printf("swap %d ", count);
            }
        }
    }

    // Print results:
    printf("\n----------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Input Names \tSorted names\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t\t\t%s\n", tname[i], name[i]);
    }
    printf("------------------------------------------\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
7 dHea bbcx abcd cbcd cbad bbcd cbaa
```

The result:

```
Enter the number of names
Enter 7 names
swap 1 swap 2 swap 3 swap 4 swap 5 swap 6 swap 7 swap 8 swap 9 swap 10 swap 11 swap 12 swap 13 
----------------------------------------
Input Names     Sorted names
------------------------------------------
dHea            abcd
bbcx            bbcd
abcd            bbcx
cbcd            cbaa
cbad            cbad
bbcd            cbcd
cbaa            dHea
```

---

[reference](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-sort-names-alphabetical-order)

So for the same set of data we needed 13 swaps in the bubble sort algorithm instead of 8 as in the alpha algorithm.

(This particular bubble sort uses `strcpy` function versus swapping pointers.)

My conclusion is that presented "alpha sort" algorithm will be **always** more efficient than classical bubble sort. This is due to the fact that we start sorting right away successively adding elements to the sorted list. Basically we can treat this algorithm as improved bubble sort.

It is worth to note that the growing list is always sorted which can be very useful for some types of applications.

Comment: It's rather hard to imaging why, if you are calling sort from `list_add`, you don't simply add the node in sort order. It requires nothing more than iterating until you find the node before the new node and insert it there (e.g. inserting `cbcd`, iterate `a,b,c,cb,cba,[insert here]`. Inserting the node at the beginning and then calling a full list sort for every insertion, becomes more an more inefficient as the list size grows. Best just to insert the node in sort order if you are sorting from `list_add`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It is not "full sort". We do not copy elements but just swap pointers. Could you post your proposal for `void list_add(t_file **alst, t_file *newElement);` and `void sort_alpha(t_file **begin_list);` so we can compare the efficiency? I am curious if it can be done less costly and still works.

Comment: Well, I know what the code does, my point being that you swap *every* pointer up to the sort-order insertion point, when you could have simply inserted at the insertion point. The alternative is to take `sort_alpha` out of `list_add` completely and just call it once after all the data is read. As written, you needlessly insert a node out of order as the beginning node and then swap every pointer up to where the added node should fit -- *for every node added*. I'm not saying your code doesn't work, I'm just saying it would be hard to code a less-efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @sg7 Thanks for help, it works but it has difficulty sorting mixed case.

Comment: @TenTenPeter I think you may be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646734/how-to-sort-an-array-of-string-alphabetically-case-sensitive-nonstandard-colla?lq=1