# Sorting strings content inside array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Trying to find a way to sort the content of some strings in an array. For example, {b,a,d,c}{f,e,g,h} will become {a,b,c,d}{e,f,g,h}.

Wrote a code that only able to sort the first string, using the ASCII table, using the same concept as bubble sort.

```
void InsertionSortChars(char str[]) {

    int i, k = 0, size = 0;
    size= strlen(str);
    char temp;
    if (size <= 0)
        return;
    while (k < size)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] < str[i + 1])
                continue;
            else
            {
                temp = str[i];
                str[i] = str[i + 1];
                str[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
char str[] = "badc\0djfkjlg";
int x=strlen(str);
char test1_a[M][M] = { "abcdefgjjjjjj", "gfegtt", "abcd" };
char test1_b[M][M] = { "cdefgba", "geff", "abcde" };
InsertionSortChars(test1_a[1][0]);
InsertionSortChars(test1_b[1][0]);
printf("%s\n\n", str);
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

What can I do to improve it and make it arrange the rest of the strings?
Thank you!

Comment: I edited your question to use a proper code block formatting please check. You say you want to sort "string in an array", ie. an array of strings, ie `char *strings[] = { "first string", "second string" }`, yet your function takes a single pointer to a string (where string is a character array). Do you want to sort _characters_ in a string? What exactly are you passing to the function? How are you calling the function? What exactly does `{b,a,d,c}{f,e,g,h}` represent? How is the parameter passed to the function initialized?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of string alphabetically (case sensitive, nonstandard collation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646734/how-to-sort-an-array-of-string-alphabetically-case-sensitive-nonstandard-colla)

Comment: Hi friend, my teacher gave us an assignment to write a code that compares between 2 given arrays of strings and check if the same string is in those 2 arrays (can be more than one..).
enterd my main() to the original post